Query VM-Ware API with Python to get PCI Devices of VMs
I want to query data from our VMWare using pyVmomi.
I can run the basic connection that you get from.
](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/8.0/vsphere-apis-sdks-getting-started/GUID-86B616CD-38B9-4795-917D-8211CB1C33EA.html)
This works fine.
hostname = 'vc1.example.com'
username = 'administrator@vsphere.local'
password = 'TooSecret2C!'

from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect
from vmware.vapi.vsphere.client import create_vsphere_client, VsphereClient
import requests, urllib3
import sys
from pyVmomi import vim

def connect(host: str, user: str, pwd: str, insecure: bool) -> tuple[VsphereClient, vim.ServiceInstance]:
    session = requests.session()
    if insecure:
        session.verify = False
        urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
    print('Creating an Automation API session.')
    vsphere_client = create_vsphere_client(host, user, pwd, session=session)
    print('Creating a VIM/SOAP session.')
    si = SmartConnect(host=host, 
                      user=user,
                      pwd=pwd,
                      disableSslCertValidation=insecure)
    return vsphere_client, si

(vsphere_client, service_instance) = connect(hostname,
                                             username,
                                             password,
                                             insecure=True)

But I don't understand how you get more information about this API
For my Purpose I would like to get the PCI devices of each VM. And get the Graphic Devices of our hosts. I can query all the VMS via, but I only get part of the Data I need
vsphere_client.vcenter.VM.list()
Is there something I missed about this?
I looked into the community Samples. But I thought there might be a more centralized documentation for everything pyVmomi can do.
I tried to connect and that worked. I read some Documentation but did not find the Data I was looking for. I found some interesting block posts but with deprecated Information.
